# I have used sabon base font i want sabon math font in latex

Tags: symbols

We are using Sabon base font in latex sample How to create the math font in miktex 2.9

Regard
Pramod

Comment: You have to use antother math font. As far as I know Sabon has no own math

Comment: Minion Pro goes well with Sabon, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard - One might add that `Minion Math` is not a free font.

Comment: @Mico: I was thinking of the `MinionPro` package, which has  scripts to make maths fonts from the  MinionPro fonts which come with Acrobat Reader, with help of the `LCDF Type Tools`. Requires somework from the user, of course.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Sabon Math font (that I know of).  You can, however, combine any text font with any math font.  Many sources have recommended [that Sabon goes well with the math font Euler.](https://math.ucsd.edu/~msharpe/mathsamples.pdf)  (This is available in OpenType as Neo Euler.)

To load a version of Sabon with `unicode-math`, let’s say the Sabon LT Std from Linotype that does not contain most Greek letters, but does have the infinity symbol, you might do something like this (warning: untested).

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase }
\setmainfont{SabonLTStd}[
  Scale = 1.0 ,
  Ligatures = {Common, TeX} ,
  UprightFont = *-Roman ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf ]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{latin,Latin,digits}, \infty}]{Sabon LT Std Roman}
\setmathfont[range={it/{latin,Latin,digits}]{Sabon LT Std Italic}
\setmathfont[range={bfup/{latin,Latin,digits}]{Sabon LT Std Bold}
\setmathfont[range={bfit/{latin,Latin,digits}]{Sabon LT Std Bold Italic}
```

Replace the names with the version of the font you own.

If you would rather use a legacy math font, you can do so with `mathastext` or, in XeLaTeX, `mathspec`.

If you need the document to be compatible with PDFLaTeX, or if you have only a Type 1 version of the fonts, the package `sabon` is available if you own the font from Linotype.  There is also a package `savoy` for a clone of the font, which is also a commercial font.